# How un-theme all the tinymce windows using a diazo theme

Tags: plone, xdv, diazo

I made a nice complex style theme in Diazo, but I don't want to theme all the TinyMce (popup) windows.

Surely there is a clever way to make it using the rules file.
Any suggestions?

Thank's
Vito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to make sure your theme has a condition like this:

```
<theme href="theme.html" css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" />
```

This way, no theme is applied to anything that isn't a page rendered with main_template (which would have a div with id visual-portal-wrapper).

Martin

Comment: And this is in the documentation of plone.app.theming ... /me should read documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here is to add response headers to Products.TinyMCE to switch off theming. See: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#disabling-the-theme-for-a-particular-view-script-or-template